# When i upload aab file with API 31 on play console.it doesn't work in android 12 devices

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, google-developers-console

Your app current targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31.  this is the error  got when i tried to upload lower Api AAB...lower APi 30 working fine in android 12 devices but i can not upload it on Play console.. Help me guys....

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.3
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 76.81 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.11 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.5.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.11.07.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.4, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
      Build Tools: 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.0, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0
      System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: 13.3/13E113 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

i expect the app to work in android 12 devices on GooglePlaystore ..

Answer (score 0):

go to build.gradle file in your project and
change targetSdkVersion  to 31

```html
  defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.appli"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: it didn't work brother